# What is this letter about?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

You open your mail to find a mysterious note - whoever wrote it, they didn't sign their name!

> Long time no talk - I've been busy writing!
>   In fact, I've been invited to give a speech on it.
>   To be honest, I'm a little worried about being so visible.
>   Fortunately, a buddy of mine will be helping me with security.
>   Those gators can be pretty scary, you know.
>   Afterwards, I'm jamming with one of my musician friends.
>   It'll be pitch perfect!
>   (Don't make that sour face at me, you know you love terrible puns.)

What is this letter about?

---

Hint (how to solve):

> Each line contains a clue to a word or phrase. All of those have something in common which will lead you to the answer word.

Hint (clues):

> Your friend is definitely not writing all those things by hand..

Comment: About some people who have run out of ideas for speeches and parties

Comment: 'pitch perfect' is a movie, 'gators' is a football team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have a partial answer?

> something about keys?

Long time no talk - I've been busy writing!

> typically the phrase is long time no SEE, but that doesn't quite fit my guess. EDIT: is it that he's typing on a keyboard?

In fact, I've been invited to give a speech on it.

> could be the *key*note speaker

To be honest, I'm a little worried about being so visible.

> "keyed up"? meaning anxious?

Fortunately, a buddy of mine will be helping me with security.

> safely under lock and key?

Those gators can be pretty scary, you know.

> in the florida keys?

Afterwards, I'm jamming with one of my musician friends.

> a keyboard player?

It'll be pitch perfect!

> on key

(Don't make that sour face at me, you know you love terrible puns.)

> is this a line too? Sour=key lime??

Comment: Yes!! Minor differences from my explanation: "visible" -> "public ___", "jamming" -> "___tar" (an attempt at wordplay) - but your answers fit just as well. Nicely done!

Comment: Oh, and "Long time no talk" is just me mangling the usual phrase since your "friend" is catching up over text.. call it a red herring :P